# Parse exception using jaxb

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to generate Java classes from xsd by using jaxb2 maven plugin and I am getting the following exception:

> [ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [xyz.xsd{9,84}].org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unsupported binding namespace "http://annox.dev.java.net". Perhaps you meant "http://jaxb2commons.dev.java.net/basic"? at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.error (AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.java:213)

**Namespace declaration :**

```
xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox"
```

**Plugin :**

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <extension>true</extension>
      <args>
         <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
      </args>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2 </version>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </configuration>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>2.9.3</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```